# Type assertion failed with correct casting from interface{} in golang

Tags: go

Here is the output I am getting from the simple repro case below:

```
2015/06/22 21:09:50 ok: false
2015/06/22 21:09:50 stub: *main.Stub <nil>
```

Clearly the stub is correctly marked as pointer to Stub type but the casting failed. I am trying to update the content of the array.

```
package main

import "log"

const BUFFER_SIZE = 8

type Value struct {
    value int
}

func (v Value) Value() int          { return v.value }
func (v *Value) SetValue(value int) { v.value = value }

type Stub struct {
    Value
    testString string
}

type StubFactory struct{}
type FactoryInterface interface {
    NewInstance(size int) []interface{}
}

func (factory StubFactory) NewInstance(size int) []interface{} {
    stubs := make([]interface{}, size)
    for i, _ := range stubs {
        stubs[i] = &Stub{Value: Value{i}, testString: ""}
    }
    return stubs
}

type Buffer struct {
    values []interface{}
}

func NewBuffer(factory FactoryInterface, size int) *Buffer {
    return &Buffer{values: factory.NewInstance(size)}
}

func (buf *Buffer) Get(index int) interface{} {
    return &buf.values[index]
}

func main() {
    stubFactory := &StubFactory{}
    buffer := NewBuffer(stubFactory, BUFFER_SIZE)

    index := 0
    if stub, ok := buffer.Get(index).(*Stub); ok { // THIS FAILS :-(
        log.Printf("ok: %+v\n", ok)
        log.Printf("stub: %T %+v\n", stub, stub)
        stub.SetValue(1234)
        log.Printf("value:%+v\n", buffer.Get(index)) // I WANT "1234"
    } else {
        log.Printf("ok: %+v\n", ok)
        log.Printf("stub: %T %+v\n", stub, stub) // but this shows the right type
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a minor remark on terminology - the Go developers use the term '[type conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)' instead of 'casting'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is:

```
func (buf *Buffer) Get(index int) interface{} {
    return &buf.values[index]
}
```

You want to do:

```
func (buf *Buffer) Get(index int) interface{} {
    return buf.values[index]
}
```

When you return &buf.values[index] you are returning a pointer to an interface. Which is a *(*Stub) (in a sense)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I tripped in the interface thingie before and will do it again. I don't grok the way golang deals with interface{} vs. pointers. I'll try to read more material about it until it clicks. Stay safe with the tornadoes out there in IL.

Comment: Think of an interface as a struct with a type and value field.  The type is checked when you do the assertion someInterfaceVar.(ConcreteType).  Since go values are just raw data, they have to include the type of the data so runtime safety can be maintained.

Comment: Okay that helps. I still believe the compiler could have warned me about this? Apparently the type being displayed correctly when ok == false is a sign that something is not reported correctly. Don't you think?

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing.  Probably comes from String() showing the concrete value and never the reference type (ie interface type itself)